# How do you scale a vector using the Haskell library, Linear?

Tags: haskell, haskell-linear

This is a simple question about style. I've been using:

```
import Linear
point  = V3 1 2 3
scaled = fmap (* 2) point
```

Or...

```
scaled = (* 2) <$> point
```

Is this the intended way, or is there a proper multiplication by scalar operator?

Comment: The [`linear`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.16) package does not export `Data.Linear`, can you link to the library you're using?

Comment: Woops, it was a typo. Thanks.

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.20.7/docs/Linear-Vector.html#v:scaled

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `linear` library exports an instance of `Num a => Num (V3 a)`, so you can actually just do

```
> point * 2
V3 2 4 6
```

If you use GHCi, you can see what it means for `2 :: V3 Int`:

```
> 2 :: V3 Int
V3 2 2 2
```

So the implementation of `fromInteger` for `V3` would look like

```
fromInteger n = V3 n' n' n' where n' = fromInteger n
```

This means you can do things like

```
> point + 2
V3 3 4 5
> point - 2
V3 (-1) 0 1
> abs point
V3 1 2 3
> signum point
V3 1 1 1
> negate point
V3 (-1) (-2) (-3)
```

`V3` also implements `Fractional`, so you should be able to use `/` and co. when your point contains `Fractional` values.  However, the use of `fmap` is more general, you can convert your `V3 Int` into `V3 String`, for example:

```
> fmap show point
V3 "1" "2" "3"
```

The `fmap` function will let you apply a function of type `a -> b` to a `V3 a` to get a `V3 b` without any restrictions on the output type (necessarily so).  Using `fmap` is not wrong, it's just not as readable as using the normal arithmetic operators.  Most Haskellers wouldn't have any problems reading it, though, `fmap` is a very general tool that shows up for just about every type out there.

Comment: Oh. That's awkward, I didn't expect the type to be so flexible and was looking for a "scale" function. This makes complete sense. Thank you.

Comment: @Viclib: well... it makes _some_ sense, but not really "complete sense". That `Num` instance is mathematically rather adventurous. Of course, Edward knows what he's doing, still I recommend the [vector-space package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space) for a better interface. Scaling is expressed with [`*^`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.8.7/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html#v:-42--94-) there.